# How to use expression syntax with a class the implements IDispoable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my code I have more of these than I am proud of:

```
public List<User> GetUsers(string userPath, string userName)
{
   using (userRepo Repo = new Repo(){
      return repo.GetUsers(userPath, userName)
   }
}
```

I do this because I implement IDisposable in my userRepo and don't need it hanging around, so I new one up to these calls.  But the syntax seems really heavy.

As an example of what I'd like to do, I love that I can implement the Expression Body syntax:

```
//normal syntax
public int DoubleTheValue(int someValue)
{
    return someValue * 2;
}

//expression syntax
public int DoubleTheValue(int someValue) => someValue * 2;
```

What is the expression syntax equivalent to new up an instance of a class, call a method on it, and dispose it?

Barring that, is there an easy option to simplify my `GetUsers` sample?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid multiple `using`s, within the same class on your repo?

Comment: `is there an easy option to simplify my GetUsers sample?` -- Are you using an IoC container? (Autofac, etc.)

Comment: @MarkC. no DI yet for this particular project.  And to JonathanBarclay, i want to avoid the usings. I want the repo to be disposed after every call.

Comment: @canton7 if I implemented an expression body finalizer, such as shown here, could that help?  If so, could you show me how that syntax woudl look? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors

Comment: @FoxDeploy DO NOT rely on finalizers. If something is `IDisposable`, then you need to call `Dispose()` on it at the appropriate time.

Comment: I am very intrigues, Canton.  Why not rely on finalizers?  I would love more reading on the topic :)

Comment: There is lots of reading to be had! Pretty much any search engine search for "C# finalizer" will put you on a good path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither using statements nor using declarations can be used directly in an expression-bodied member.

You could however write a helper method, if you don't mind a small amount of additional runtime cost:

```
private static T QueryRepo<T>(Func<Repo, T> func)
{
    using (var repo = new Repo())
    {
        return func(repo);
    }
}
```

Allowing you to write:

```
public List<User> GetUsers(string userPath, string userName) =>
    QueryRepo(repo => repo.GetUsers(userPath, userName));
```

Comment: The helper method construct is perfect for my usage.  Thanks!